# Помогите запустить tomcat в Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Windows 10
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Ultimate Edition)
JDK 17.0.4
Tomcat 9.0.70

Помогите запустить tomcat, 3-ий день уже пытаюсь, не могу разобраться в чем ошибка.
через командную панель запустить файл startup.bat не удается. Окно открывается пишет код и ничего не открывается (http://localhost:8080/ не работает).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если нужны лого приложу в коментарии

переменные среды добавлены в Path
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально планировалось запустить в IntelliJ IDEA, вот структура проекта и контроллер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот настройки Tomcat
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот файл pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCApp1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCApp1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncording>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncording>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>

    <spring.version>6.0.2</spring.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCApp1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering/>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContextMvc.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.user.springcourse"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

При запуске через IntelliJ IDEA сервер запускается, но открывается только http://localhost:8080/,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как понял это из файла индекс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
далее путь http://localhost:8080/hello не открывается и выводит ошибку,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя ожидалось это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
стек по запуску tomcat тоже прикладываю

```html
"C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2022-12-20 08:38:01,842] Artifact SpringMVCApp1:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.70
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.846 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 1 2022 14:05:47 UTC
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.847 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.70.0
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.847 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ РћРЎ:             10.0
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РђСЂС…РёС‚РµРєС‚СѓСЂР°:           amd64
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ JVM:            17.0.4+11-LTS-179
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.854 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.854 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.854 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b\conf\logging.properties
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.856 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b\jmxremote.password
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b\jmxremote.access
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.860 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\tomcat\1b719e08-1f73-42ce-831f-9bc239dfff9b
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.862 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.863 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\temp
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0].
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:03.878 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:04.531 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:04.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1301] milliseconds
20-Dec-2022 20:38:04.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:04.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:04.683 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:05.051 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [455] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2022-12-20 08:38:05,505] Artifact SpringMVCApp1:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
20-Dec-2022 20:38:06.922 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
20-Dec-2022 20:38:07.224 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [215] milliseconds.
[2022-12-20 08:38:07,304] Artifact SpringMVCApp1:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2022-12-20 08:38:07,305] Artifact SpringMVCApp1:war exploded: Deploy took 1,799 milliseconds
20-Dec-2022 20:38:15.082 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\webapps\manager]
20-Dec-2022 20:38:15.413 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Java prog\apache-tomcat-9.0.70\webapps\manager] has finished in [330] ms
```

Comment: Вам нужно убрать Servlet Context Path в настройках деплоя томката в ИДЕЕ. Должно решить проблему

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите более конкретно как это сделать
Service-tomcat-EditConfiguration-Deploymet??
Но там только один name:war exploded